# Правильная разметка названий в теле вопроса/ответа

Tags: обсуждение, правки

Столкнулся с неоднозначностью в подходе оформления названий в тексте:

*Вариант №1:*

Оформлять без разметки: Python

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1011982/3

*Вариант №2:*

Оформлять внутри блока кода: `Python`

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1012093/2

*Вариант №3:*

Без разницы. Оба варианта - допустимы.

---

Каким образом действовать в дальнейшем?

Comment: Python - это название языка. Не стоит выделять его как код.

Comment: Возможно, стоит добавить в Справку отдельную статью, о том как должно быть оформлено сообщение? Я нашел там только информацию о синтаксисе. Мне кажется, что "общая стилистика" - важный момент и должен присутствовать в Справке, а не только в обсуждениях Меты.